# Multiboot ubuntu, Elementary, Windows, joint swap or sparate ones?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, swap

I've been using Ubuntu for a long time with dual boot alongside windows 7, and used EasyBCD software to create Linux entry in the MBR, now I want to install Elementary without damaging either Ubuntu or Windows using the same method.

Is it safe according to your experience, also do I need a separate Swap partition or one is enough for both distros (Ubuntu and Elementary) ?

Comment: If you are not going to hibernate your computer, there's no problem. Otherwise, make sure to boot into the last distro you put in hibernation (and shutting down normally) before switching to the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to have a triple boot setup as long as you have enough empty hard drive space. Make sure you backup before partitioning.

You can use the same Swap partition since it is used only while the OS is running. But do not hibernate one OS and then boot in another OS, because when you go back to the first one, it will not be able to wake up from hibernation.